# What are the enhancements done in usage of thread in java 7?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

Its nice to see that are lot improvements done in java 7 release which is a good news for developers. Since thread is an essential part of core java, I was curious to know what are the enhancements done in thread in java 7 ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. It’s for asking *actual programming questions*. If you want to know, what has changed, you should be able to find the documentation yourself. Try for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/cl-mt.html):

> The Java SE 7 release contains an important enhancement for
>   multithreaded custom class loaders. In previous releases, certain
>   types of custom class loaders were prone to deadlock. **The Java SE 7
>   release modifies the locking mechanism to avoid deadlock.**

Also refer: [Enhancements in Packages java.lang.* and java.util.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/enhancements.html)